# Remove style from one list

Tags: html, css, list

I would like you to help me with this exercise that i'm doing. I'm wanting to remove the style from a simple list. I have the html and the css, so in the css i'm trying to remove the style with the following lines of code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="Start.html">Start</a></li>
    <li><a href="Products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS code:

[CSS code en visual studio code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEsMJ.png)

I do not understand that if i'm writing wrong if I do not get any error, according to the program and the result is the following:

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TWXP.png)

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong, please.

Comment: Please post the code as text.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write *none* in quotes, you simply write:
`text-decoration: none`

You can read more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration

Answer (score 0):

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="Start.html">Start</a></li>
    <li><a href="Products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```